# Как разместить иконку и текст в кнопки слево, справо, снизу, сверху?

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент button. В нём есть тег i где есть иконка. Нужно выровнять иконку и текст кнопки слева, справа, снизу, сверху при помощи css. Заранее спасибо!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--подключение иконочного шрифта-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/libs/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>
      Кнопка
      <i class='fa fa-commenting i1' aria-hidden='true'></i>
      <!--выровнить i и текст кнопки слево, справо, снизу и сверху кнопки-->
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: оно и так ровно отображается. Уточните пожалуйста ваш вопрос